# require() from another directory in PHP

Tags: php, directory, include

I have a problem with directory in PHP. This is my directory structure

```
--root/dashboard/index.php
--root/includes/config.php
```

Now i want to include `config.php` in `index.php` !

What i tried :

In `index.php` I have added this:

```
<?php 
if ( file_exists(dirname(__DIR__).'/includes/config.php') ) {
  echo ' It exists';
  echo dirname(__DIR__).'/includes/config.php';
  require(dirname(__DIR__).'/includes/config.php');
}
?>
```

> output : It exists/storage/h9/767/1486767/public_html/includes/config.php

but codes after it won't execute. If I put require out of if statement it show me `error 500`.

PS 1 : Maybe this help : if I put `index.php` in root directory and require like this

```
require('includes/config.php');
```

everything work fine.

Comment: Check your webserver logs for the error message you are getting

Comment: But the value of the constant __DIR__ is the correct path?

Comment: @RogerRV It should be . because the echo show the file and path exists

Comment: `if ( file_exists('dirname(__DIR__)./includes/config.php') ) {` is wrong, that should be `if ( file_exists( dirname(__DIR__) . '/includes/config.php' ) ) {`

Comment: @RamRaider you are right but it happened in rewrite here :) in my file i wrote `if ( file_exists(dirname(__DIR__).'/includes/config.php') )`

Comment: @RamRaider Yes i see it now the ' ' declares string you can't include variables inside string quotes

Comment: The code is correct...!

Comment: @AnkitJain any suggestion ?

Comment: what's the error your code is showing ?